# Upper bound of limit of convergent infinite sum of cauchy sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k^{(n)}-x_k^{(m)}|<\varepsilon$ for all $m,n>N$ where $(x^{(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a cauchy sequence in the $l^1$ space with standard norm and $x^{(n)}=(x^{(n)}_1,\dots, x^{(n)}_k, \dots)$. If it already has been shown that $x_k^{(n)}\rightarrow x_k$ can it be shown that

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k^{(n)}-x_k^{(m)}|<\varepsilon \longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k-x_k^{(m)}|\le\varepsilon$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

somehow? I have already knowledge about the dominated convergence theorem, what's nagging me is

1) Why the lesser than sign turns into a lesser than or equal to sign

2) How one can be sure that the limit of the expression is still bounded by $\varepsilon$.

Comment: 1) is a property of inequalities that is in the nature of things. The inequality $f(n)<\text{something}$ becomes, in the limit, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)\le \text{something}$. In general you lose the strict inequality: take for example $f(n)=1-\frac1n$, which is strictly smaller than $1$ for all $n$, but is equal to $1$ in the limit.

Comment: You can think at (2) abstractly, by writing $\sum_k \lvert x^{(n)}_k - x^{(m)}_k\rvert=\lVert x^{(n)} -x^{(m)}\rVert_1$. In a normed space, the norm is always a continuous function.